# Django not receiving data from ajax

Tags: django, ajax

I've been trying to work and understand ajax without relying on jquery for learning purposes.

I'm sending data I got from a textfield.

Here's my ajax

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

   document.getElementById('id_tags').onkeyup = () => {

       // initialize new request
       const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
       request.open("POST", "{% url 'tag_suggestions' %}");

       var keyword = document.getElementById('id_tags').value;
       data = {"keyword": keyword};

       //when request is finished
       request.onload = () => {
            console.log("Test");
         }


       //send request
       request.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", '{{csrf_token}}');
       request.send(JSON.stringify(data));

   };

});
```

Here's the django function that listens on my ajax requests

```
def tag_suggestions(request):
    print('inside tag_suggestions ')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print(request.POST.keys())
        return ('Test')

    else:
        print('not ajax Test')
        return HttpResponse('Test')
```

I've tested my javascript code it's just fine. It listens on events, got the value properly.

But in my django, when it executes `request.POST.keys()`, the output will be

```
dict_keys([])
```

and I concluded that I'm not receiving the data from my ajax request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it was mentioned, you can access your POST data as follows:

```
data = json.loads(request.body)
```

I think you'd also need to set a `Content-Type` header in your JS Ajax for it to work though:

```
request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", 'application/json;');
```

P.S. Feels more like a comment, but I can't comment for now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to init the `ajax` call

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'your url',
  method: 'POST',
  data: {"keyword": keyword},
  success: function(response) {
      # response is the data what is returned from the view, in
      # your case, from tag_suggestions
  }
});
```

And on `django` side, you need to return a `json_response` not a `httpResponse`

And of course, check if the request is `ajax` . Don't remember the correct
syntax, but something like

```
if request.is_ajax
```

Maybe you will need additional checking based on request type

Comment: Thanks but I'm not using jquery.

Answer (score 0):

The data of your post as Json should be load by the json model.

```
def tag_suggestions(request):
    print('inside tag_suggestions ')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = json.loads(request.body)
        print(data)
        return ('Test')

    else:
        print('not ajax Test')
        return HttpResponse('Test')
```